# SpriteKit unable to unarchive an SKEmitterNode subclass from sks file

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have the following code:

```
final class PassthroughEmitterNode: SKEmitterNode {
  
  static func load(fnWithoutExtension: String, in bundle: Bundle) -> SKEmitterNode? {
    guard
      let sksPath = bundle.path(forResource: fnWithoutExtension, ofType: "sks"),
      let sksData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sksPath)),
      let unarchiver = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: sksData),
      let texturePath = bundle.path(forResource: fnWithoutExtension, ofType: "png"),
      let textureImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: texturePath)
    else { return nil }
    
    // Required to decode into subclass
    unarchiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKEmitterNode")
    let emitter = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as? PassthroughEmitterNode
    unarchiver.finishDecoding()
    
    guard let emitter else { return nil }
    
    // We still need to set texture, because the texture file is not in main bundle
    emitter.particleTexture = SKTexture(image: textureImage)
    
    // Have to enable user interaction to receive touch
    emitter.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    return emitter
  }
}
```

This is very similar to reading a SKScene subclass instance from SKS file (such as this: [using sks file with SKScene subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212771/using-sks-file-with-skscene-subclass)).

However, this doesn't work. The unarchiver's decoding always returns nil.

But unarchiving to `SKEmitterNode` class itself works. The subclass doesn't work.

Comment: What happens if you replace `self.classForKeyedUnarchiver()` with the name of your subclass, `PassthroughEmitterNode.self`, in the call to `unarchiver.setClass`? When I had a similar problem archiving and unarchiving SpriteKit objects, I had to use the subclass name when setting the archiver's class. See the following article: [Saving with NSKeyedArchiver](https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/scene-editor-development-saving-with-nskeyedarchiver/).

Comment: @SwiftDevJournal Still nil. Same as before. It only works if I don't use the subclass.

Comment: If you have a sks file you just need to get the skscene from the file and what you need from it. You do not need unarchive and I do not think that the sks file format is archive format.

Comment: @PtitXav oh sks file is not just for skscene, but also for particles (SKEmitterNode). In my case it's used for particles.

Comment: So just get the skemitternode from the file using SKEmitterNode(fileNamed:)

Comment: @PtitXav this only works if the sks is in the main bundle. My sks is in a different bundle.

Comment: Can you just copy the sks in your bundle ?

Comment: what do you mean by copy the sks in my bundle? are you saying moving sks from my other bundle to the main bundle?

Comment: i have various reasons putting some of my assets and codes in other modules (e.g. maintainability, sharing code/assets across multiple games, etc). putting them to main isn't an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try this strategy:

1. Decode `SKEmitterNode`
2. Create a `PassthroughEmitterNode` from a `SKEmitterNode`

In order to do that let's add this init

```
public final class PassthroughEmitterNode: SKEmitterNode {
    
    init(emitterNode: SKEmitterNode) {
        super.init()

        self.emissionAngle = emitterNode.emissionAngle
        self.emissionAngleRange = emitterNode.emissionAngleRange
        self.numParticlesToEmit = emitterNode.numParticlesToEmit
        self.particleAlpha = emitterNode.particleAlpha
        self.particleAlphaRange = emitterNode.particleAlphaRange
        self.particleAlphaSpeed = emitterNode.particleAlphaSpeed
        self.particleBirthRate = emitterNode.particleBirthRate
        self.particleBlendMode = emitterNode.particleBlendMode
        self.particleColor = emitterNode.particleColor
        self.particleColorBlendFactor = emitterNode.particleColorBlendFactor
        self.particleColorBlendFactorRange = emitterNode.particleColorBlendFactorRange
        self.particleColorBlendFactorSpeed = emitterNode.particleColorBlendFactorSpeed
        self.particleLifetime = emitterNode.particleLifetime
        self.particleLifetimeRange = emitterNode.particleLifetimeRange
        self.particlePositionRange = emitterNode.particlePositionRange
        self.particleRotation = emitterNode.particleRotation
        self.particleRotationRange = emitterNode.particleRotationRange
        self.particleRotationSpeed = emitterNode.particleRotationSpeed
        self.particleScale = emitterNode.particleScale
        self.particleScaleRange = emitterNode.particleScaleRange
        self.particleScaleSpeed = emitterNode.particleScaleSpeed
        self.particleSpeed = emitterNode.particleSpeed
        self.particleSpeedRange = emitterNode.particleSpeedRange
        self.particleTexture = emitterNode.particleTexture
        self.position = emitterNode.position
        self.xAcceleration = emitterNode.xAcceleration
        self.yAcceleration = emitterNode.yAcceleration
        // TODO: Add additional properties I might have forgot.
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

That's it.

Now you can decode a standard `SKEmitterNode` and convert it into your `PassthroughEmitterNode`

```
let emitterNode: SKEmitterNode = ... // Decode as usual
let passthroughEmitterNode = PassthroughEmitterNode(emitterNode: emitterNode)
```

### What if `PassthroughEmitterNode` has additional properties compared to `SKEmitterNode`?

The value for these additional properties cannot come from the `sks` file since there is no place for them. So you will need to populate them using some default value or custom logic.

Comment: What if SKEmitterNode introduces a new field in new iOS release?

Comment: @OMGPOP Can you make a more specific example? I don't think you want the behaviour of your game to change automatically in a new iOS release so I don't see the problem here.

Comment: no specific example. I just think that this approach is a bit hard to maintain and may easily go wrong if apple adds another field, and we have to remember to include that in our code as well. I am hoping to get a better way of doing things. but if not, i will accept this answer